# Swiperjs. How can I pass custom props to SwiperSlide and get it onSlideChange function?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I am in a different situation. I am using Swiper.js for my React app. I need to change app theme color on slide changes and it have to be dynamic. That's I need to pass some props to SwiperSlide and get this props on slide change. How can I handle that ?

```js
    <Swiper
      id="pathway-slider"
      slidesPerView={1}
      onSlideChange={(swiper) => {
        console.log("Slide index changed to: ", swiper);
      }}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>
          Slide 1
      </SwiperSlide>
      
      <SwiperSlide>
          Slide 2
      </SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
```

When I `console.log(swiper)` it gives me huge object where I can access activeSlideIndex or etc. But how can I pass custom data to that ?

Comment: Hi did you find a solution to this. Im using typescript and I cant find any way to add additional prop to swipper core without having typescript errors

Comment: Hi, I am also using typescript. I don't know it's the right way or not but I only find solution by adding "accessKey" property.         
<SwiperSlide
          accessKey={`${item.pathwayId} ${item.playerPathwayId}`}
          key={item.pathwayId}
        >
 ... 
</SwiperSlider>

Comment: A solution for people trying to use material ui and swipper is to wrapper the the swipper component in material styled and them pass your props through the sx={{}}  for some reason this doesn't throw a type script flag

Answer (score 2):

A solution for people trying to use `material UI and` swiper`is to wrapper the swiper component in a`material styled component`and then pass your props through the`sx={{}}`for some reason this doesn't throw a`typescript flag`

Import styled

```
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
```

Wrapper `Swiper` in `styled`

```
const StyledSwiper = styled(Swiper)(({ theme }: any) => ({
  padding: "20px 0 70px 0",
}));
```

Add `Custom Swipper` to your `page` or `component`

```
<StyledSwiper
        ...some_default_PROPS
        sx={{
          "& .swiper-slide": {
            transition: "all 3s ease",
            transform: isHomePage ? "scale(0.8)" : "initial",
          },
          "& .swiper-slide-active": {
            transform: isHomePage ? "scale(1.1)" : "initial",
          },
          "& .swiper-pagination": {
            bottom: "0",
          },
        }}
      >  {data?.length > 0 &&
          data.map(((node,index)) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={node?.id}>
              <div> Slide {index}</div>
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
      </StyledSwiper>
```

Comment: So you want scale the Slider if the Slider show up on home page ?

Comment: If it's so why don't you pass the conditional class name to SwiperSlide ?         <SwiperSlide
          className={isHomePage ? "home-page" :  ""}
        > 
...
</SwiperSlide>
  Later change your css according to that className.

Comment: this is just one of the use cases you can also pass it on the <SwiperSlide> component and it would be the same thing you will get typescript error.  To answer which not just use className property cause for this project we aren't using any classes directly at all we are using Mui styled and Material Styled for that whole thing an so we do want to have a class just for this small bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass down the custom data on the `SwiperSlide` component as `data-id` and then access it from the `onSlideChange` event, using the dataset id. Heres an example:

The component:

```
 <Swiper
      onSlideChange={(e) => handleSwiperChange(e)}
     >
                  
                          <SwiperSlide                  
                            data-id="your custom data"
                          >
                           1
                          </SwiperSlide>
                        
                  </Swiper>
```

The `handleSwiperChange` function:

```js
  const handleSwiperChange = (swiper) => {
    const activeSlide = swiper.slides[swiper.activeIndex];
    const id = activeSlide.dataset.id;
    console.log(id);
  };
```